# Find conjugate indicator function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm doubt with this problem. Let $C=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x+\frac{y^2}{2}\le 0\right\}$. I have to find $I_C^{*}(Y)$ defined by 
$I_C^{*}(Y)=\sup_{X \in \mathbb{R}^2} \left\{\langle X,Y\rangle-I_C(X)\right\}$
with $I_C$ is an idicator function of $C$.
I just know how to determine the conjugate function in 1-dimensional, but have never seen for 2-dimensional. So anybody can guide me?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

$I_C(X)$ in the expression of the $I_C^*(Y)$ can be treated as a constraint. So you get $$I^*_C(Y=\left[\array{y_1\\y_2}\right])=\sup_{x_1,x_2} x_1y_1+x_2y_2\\ \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{subject to }x_1+\frac{x_2^2}{2}\leq 0.$$ You can see that if $y_1<0$ then the supremum would be $+\infty$ as you can tend $x_1\to-\infty$. If $y_1\geq 0$ then you must have $x_1=-\frac{x_2^2}{2}$, thus you want to find $\sup_{x_2} -\frac{y_1}{2}x_2^2+y_2x_2$ which is attained at $x_2=\frac{y_2}{y_1}$. Hence, $$I_C^*(Y)=\left\lbrace\array{\frac{y_2^2}{2y_1}&,y_1>0\\+\infty&,y_1\leq0}\right. .$$